# Configuring an Existing Django Project on Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I´m starting to use Django with Pycharm IDE and have succesfully configured my first project.

However, I tried to add a new existing project to Pycharm and when trying to change the Run Configuration to use the manage.py of my secondProject(GuatepediaLocal), I don´t get an option to select it on the dropdown menu. When I try to run the project, it keeps running the PollSite manage.py runserver and not GuatepediaLocal´s manage.py runserver

Can anyone help me to solve this issue and configure an already existing Django Project on pycharm?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research I found that on the settings window of Pycharm I must add Django support to my project

[image]

That enabled the project on the dropdown menu. After that, I just added on the enviroment variables the correct path to my project´s settings.py.

[image]

Hope this helps someone someday :)

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answer. Welcome so SO!

Comment: I believe this option is not available in the free community edition.  See http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-deployment-with-pycharm/

Answer (score 4):

Open edit configuration wizard.

```
Menu > Run > Edit Configuration
```

Add new configuration by selecting the Django server from the left top button (button look like + sign). Look like below. Plus sign top left.

[image: edit configuration wizard]

If you don't configure the Django setting. It will show you the fix button to fix the Django Setting. Django Setting looks like this. You can manually set these setting by navigating like this.

```
File > Settings > Language and Framework > Django
```

Django Setting wizard looks like this.

[image: Django Setting]

set the project path, manage.py file and settings.py file.